# Possible to use mysqli to connect to Azure instead of PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, azure, mysqli, pdo

This is my code to connect to Azure:

```
<?php
$servername='myproject.database.windows.net';
$username='somename';
$password='somepassword';
$database='some_db';
$conn=New mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$database);

//Connection error handling:
// echo @mysqli_ping($conn) ? 'true' : 'false';
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("Database connection failed: " .
      mysqli_connect_error() .
      " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
  );
} else {
  // echo "Connection success";
}
?>
```

I get the error:

> Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I have tried launching this php from a WAMP server and from azurewebsites but both do not seem to work. It works with PDO but I have some pages already setup with mysqli_fetch_assoc queries and would like to preserve them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"It works with PDO but I have some pages already setup with mysqli_fetch_assoc queries and would like to preserve them."* - You're not trying to mix those two different apis together, are you? If so, you can't do that.

Comment: No, I want to use mysqli. I have just tried PDO to see if it works at all or it is some other problem.

Comment: I can't see why you couldn't connect with mysqli_ if it works on PDO; you're probably doing something wrong somewhere

Comment: But even if I only call a php page with the code above, it will not connect, what else can it be?

Comment: Maybe it's silly of me to ask, but are you sure your DB  is MySQL? If it works with PDO but not MySQLi it could be SQL Server.

Comment: I think so, I created it using mysql syntax? The PDO that works is the connection string that is shown in Azure `try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:myproject.database.windows.net,1433; Database = some_db", "somename", "somepassword");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}`

Comment: @sandboxj that connection string is obviously connecting to SQL server. (`sqlsrv`). You will need to either use PDO or `sqlsrv_*` functions. Keep in mind that PDO can connect to both MySQL and SQL Server (among others).

Comment: Ok, I need to ask a silly question back. How do I make sure it gets created as a mysql server instead?

Comment: If you are using cleardb than mysqli is not suggested for shared pricing tiers of cleardb

Comment: Actually I have managed to make it work now with cleardb. But what do you mean @prashanth ?